# JIRA: Create API documents

Tags: api, documentation, jira, confluence

Is it possible to create API documents on JIRA? If yes then how? The currently employed approach involves creating / updating a Microsoft Word document and replacing it on Confluence. This approach though fulfills the requirement but do not seems a better way for API documentation management.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading Microsoft Word documents is probably the worst way.

Although I find Confluence (and JIRA) to be terrible, I write API docs using a table and it works well:

[image: API Docs]

Once you have a template, copy and paste to grow the docs.